# DynamicGeoGraphics misplaces dynamic Points

Tags: bugs, dynamic, geographics, geodesy

**Bug introduced in 10.4 and persisting through 11.2**

CASE:3971576

---

I need to highlight a selected point in a [`DynamicGeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicGeoGraphics.html).  I use a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) [`Point`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html) to display this.

The issue is that the point displays in the correct position for [`GeoGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoGraphics.html) but displays to the far South for `DynamicGeoGraphics`.

With

```
locs = GeoPosition@#["Coordinates"] & /@ 
  EntityValue[EntityClass["AdministrativeDivision", "USStatesEastCoast"], 
    "CapitalCity"]
```

Then `GeoGraphics` behaves as expected with clicking a point resulting in the yellow point covering it.

```
DynamicModule[{selectedLoc = First@locs},
 Dynamic@GeoGraphics[
   {
    Purple, PointSize[Large],
    Button[Point@#, selectedLoc = #;] & /@ locs,
    Opacity[.75, Yellow], PointSize[.05],
    Point@selectedLoc
    }
   ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, with `DynamicGeoGraphics` the yellow point appears far to the South of the clicked point.  Below the same point is picked as above but notice the location of the yellow point.

```
DynamicModule[{selectedLoc = First@locs},
 DynamicGeoGraphics[
  {
   Purple, PointSize[Large],
   Button[Point@#, selectedLoc = #;] & /@ locs,
   Opacity[.75, Yellow], PointSize[.05],
   Dynamic[Point@selectedLoc]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any ideas what could be going on and how to fix it?

Mma 11.2 Win 7 Ent

Comment: `Dynamic` should be placed outside of `DynamicGeoGraphics`, like so: `Dynamic@DynamicGeoGraphics`. It's the same if you were to use, say, `Graphics`. `Dynamic` should not appear inside, as it is not removed during evaluation and cannot be interpreted as an argument by other functions. (I get another error message flashing when I do this, but it works other than that. Not sure what the flashing error message is about.)

Comment: @C.E. Another issue with placing the `Dynamic` outside of the `DynamicGeoGraphics` is that whenever you click a point it returns to the initial `GeoZoomLevel` and `GeoBounds`.  The UI needs to stay zoomed and panned to the location when a point is clicked.  The actual data are points across and area that need to be zoomed and panned to select.

Comment: Somethings goes off during coordinates transformation, obviously, but for `GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"` it behaves well.